# How to profile php on a shared server

Tags: php, debugging

I have a PHP website which suddenly runs slow when you enter the site. It does not run slow every time, only on the first run. I did some modification to some plugins I have, maybe something there that is causing the delay, but I have disabled them, only to see the same lags.

Is there a good way to see what exactly takes so long to load. I am on a shared environment, and there are no debugging tools available such as xdebug and pear libraries.

Does anyone know what steps I can take in getting some details on what is running.

Comment: If the environment is properly secured, you cannot find out any information about anything from other customers.

Comment: No I do not want information from other customers, I want information from my own script. I want to see what is taking so long to load within my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the [yslow](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/yslow/) add-on of firefox. This can show you why the site is slow from the client site. Take a look and also check your server side code too. If there is a query taking too much time.

You said it runs slow on very first time, it may be because of the client site load such as loading unwanted javascript code everytime. Load the javascript as they needed or you can minify the javascript.

Comment: Yes I have looked in both yslow and firefox. I am busy optimizing the site, I am aware of all the javascripts and css that are loaded in the client. I have CDN's set up and everything is ok in the client. The problem is on the server. I think the server is stuck in a loop somewhere. I can not see this in the client, as it only shows me what it got from the server.

Answer (score 0):

If you running a MySQL setup then install phpMyAdmin.  Within phpMyAdmin you'll see a tab called 'Status', from there you can get stats about the queries that are hitting your DB and what you can do to improve performance.  If the problem is JS related, then definitely install ySlow like Singh suggested.

Comment: I have phpmyadmin installed, and this could be a good option. I will check there what is hitting the DB. Thanks for the suggestion, I gave it a +1, I do not know who voted this down.

Comment: I just checked the queries for all the pages, and they are not slow. I actually had a tool that showed me all the queries and how long they took, unfortunately this was not the problem. My problem lies somewhere within PHP. Some function or setting is holding up the system. I think my best option would then be to move to a local environment and set up a xdebug system.